# FullCalendar: How to ignore timezones for full-day events? Daylight Savings Time Woes

Tags: javascript, timezone, fullcalendar

My web-application tracks events by FULL DAY only (block starting at 00:00:00, only viewed on month-view). My server generates dates without a timezone in the format of "November, 22 2011 00:00:00", which I populate into FullCalendar by simply creating a new Event object and populating the start date with:

```
new Date("November, 22 2011 00:00:00");
```

It turns out that that JavaScript "new Date()" logic looks at the date being supplied and assigns a timezone, so dates leading up to Nov 6 (daylight savings time switchover) end up getting a GMT-4, and days after get GMT-5.

As it turns out, some of my logic which creates events in a loop actually creates them one hour behind, and then throws the day on the date PREVIOUS, which is no good.

My goal here is to have the calendar function identically for ever user, whether they be in Canada or Australia. I tried forcing on server-supplied dates to GMT-0 in JS, but then everything is pushed back a day. My server only stores the date anyway, and strips off the time. It would be nice if I could "interpret" all server-supplied events as pure UTC, and then set the browser's session to think it is always -in- UTC. Then they would both talk the same language and not worry about DST.

The calendar's "ignoreTimezone" property seems to make no difference if true or false. Creating events with allDay: true has no effect.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

-Brian